# Custom RatingBar images being pulled from drawable-mdpi instead of the correct folder

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, ratingbar

I am using a custom Rating Bar with custom star images, but it is pulling the images from the wrong directory. I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 so it should be using the images from `drawable-xhdpi`, but it is using the images from `drawable-mdpi`.

***How can I make my custom Rating Bar pull the images from the right directory?***

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar_full</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/rating_bar_full.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/rating_empty" />

    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/rating_empty" />

    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/rating_filled" />

</layer-list>
```

**XML containing RatingBar**

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating_bar_friendly"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    style="@style/CustomRatingBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way to solve these problem.Put your `xhdpi images` in seperate `drawable folder`.so You doesnt need to put images seperately in xhdpi and mdpi.So that you have to `create a common folder drawable in res` and put all images there.

Comment: check out these answer and tell me what happened .so that I can help you in some other way.

Comment: I already had the different sizes for the different densities. It was just always pulling the images from the wrong folder. `mdpi` vs `xhdpi`.

Comment: That is what I am currently doing at the moment to get the correct sized image, but in the long run, the proper way would be to get the correct sized images for different screen densities.

Comment: never worry about screen densities like mdpi and xhdpi.Place your images only in drawable folder.Then you can get a output easily

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how you know it is using images from mdpi vs xhdpi?

Android will automatically select files from the correct drawables folder based on the device's screen density.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Off the top of my head, the only way I can see the images from mdpi being used is if you do not have the same file for xhdpi available.

Comment: The custom rating bar images are the size of the mdpi images vs the xhdpi images. I assumed it would automatically pick the images from the xhdpi folder since the galaxy s3 should be pulling from the xhdpi folder. The same file names were in each folder.

Comment: Perhaps the images in your xhdpi folder are not properly sized?

Comment: I followed the image sizing on the [http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) page. How would the images not be properly sized? The `xhdpi` image is bigger than the `hdpi` and smaller than `xxhdpi`.